# Corrupt file after attaching in Thunderbird

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, email, thunderbird

I'm having this annoying issue lately. Every file that I attach at some message, it goes corrupted to the receiver. And when someone send me something attached using Thunderbird I can't open the file, it says it's corrupted, but if I use the webmail interface I can download and open the file correctly, why is that ?
Why is that happening ? Any ideas ?

Comment: What version of Thunderbird are you using?. What add-ons do you have?

Comment: What E-Mail server do you use for receiving? Thunderbird has AFAIR some problems with Exchange via IMAP and attachments.

Comment: @Ramhound, I using the last one at the time, v15.

Comment: @Robert, I was using the gmail.